# Can´t upload an check Excel file on Unix system

Tags: openpyxl, fastapi

I'm trying to upload and check if one file is an Excel type, my code is:
for router:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, UploadFile,File, HTTPException, status, Depends
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from app.api.deps import get_curret_admin
from app.schemas.admin import Admins
from app.core.verify_file import check_excel

router = APIRouter()

#Upload Excel File
@router.post(
    path="/api/uploadfile/",
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
    summary="Upload a excel file",
    tags= ["Files"]
)
async def upload_file(
        file: UploadFile,
        admin: Admins= Depends(get_curret_admin)
    ):
    if not check_excel(file.file):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="El archivo no es de tipo Excel")
    return HTMLResponse("El archivo ha sido subido correctamente")
```

And check:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def check_excel(file):
    try:
        wb= load_workbook(file)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

The problem is this works fine on Windows, but Linux or macOS doesn't. In Windows check when upload an Excel file, but in Unix system all files are not Excel result, and don't accept anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finded the answer by my own, the problen was the version of python, in my mac and linux pc is under 3.11, that's the reason, there has and issue on TemporyFile under python 3.11. This solve using io.BytesIO. Like this page:

https://asiones.hashnode.dev/fastapi-receive-a-xlsx-file-and-read-it